# Как вырезать целую таблицу

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Вопрос по регуляркам.

Как из HTML документа вырезать целую таблицу?

Например:

```
....
<table id="tbl">
    .....
</table>
....
```

как в переменную загнать таблицу эту? Причем, таблица содержит другие таблицы!!!

Comment: В точности такой-же вопрос: [PHP, регулярные выражения. Извлечение строк между тегами](http://hashcode.ru/questions/15075/php-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классическая задача парных скобок.

первым делом определяем местоположение <table id="tbl"> , находим позицию и записываем в $startOffset

ищем:

```
$stack = 0;
$offset = $startOffset;

while (preg_match('~<(/?)(table.*?)>~i', $page, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $offset)) {
    if ($m[1][0] == '/') {
        $stack--;
        if ($stack <= 0) {
            echo substr($page, $startOffset, ($m[0][1] + strlen($m[0][0])) - $startOffset); // вот наш результат
            exit;
        } else {
            $stack++;
        }
        $offset = $m[0][1] + strlen($m[0][0]);
    }
}
```

как то так, я работу не проверял. Написал на глаз, суть думаю понятна.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, тут без [xml-парсера](http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.xml.php) не обойтись.

Comment: тож об этом подумал...